# itemClicked in QlistWidget, function executed more than 1 time

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a strange problem, hope someone can clear it for me

```
import os
from os import path
import sys
import pathlib
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, 
QWizard, QWizardPage, QLineEdit, \
                        QTabWidget, QApplication, 
QTextEdit,QToolTip,QPushButton,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize,pyqtSlot,pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # we are running in a bundle
    installPath = sys._MEIPASS
    print('we are running in a bundle')
else:
    # we are running in a normal Python environment
    installPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print('we are running in a normal Python environment')

UI_File, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'test.ui'))

class MainAPP(QTabWidget, UI_File):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainAPP, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.handle_buttons()
    def handle_buttons(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test_2)
    def test_2(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.listWidget.addItem(str('lklk'))
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.test)
    def test(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.listWidget_2.addItem(str('DDD'))
        self.listWidget_2.itemClicked.connect(self.test_3)
    def test_3(self):
            print ('hi')
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainAPP()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

so basically, I have a push button, if I click on it it will display some data at listWidget and if I clicked on any item in listWidget , it will display other data on ListWidget_2 and then if I click on item in List_widget_2 it then should print ('Hi')

the problem is if I click multiple times in ListWidget and then click on an item in ListWidget_2 , I received more than one ('Hi) , it will diplay ('Hi') according to the number of clicks I clicked in the Listwidget

any idea what could be the issue

Comment: Is this code actually representative of what you're doing? It seems like a contrived example. Currently, whenever you click on the first widget you make an *additional* connection to a slot for the second widget. If you really do only have two list widget objects, the the solution is to only make the connection once. Otherwise you'll need to provide a more representative example of your program (see how to make a [mcve])

Comment: yes, that is an example, but my code is will actually do exactly the same and I am receiving the same issue with both the example and my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make a connection between a signal and a slot once. Currently you are making additional connections each time you click an item in the first list widget, which results in your method printing "hi" executing once for every connection you made.

To fix this, make **both** of the signal connections either in the `test_2` method or in the `__init__` method

Comment: @Moo if this has solved your problem, please consider clicking the "tick" symbol on the left of my answer to mark it as accepted.